# React-native jsbundle from custom URL in Android

Tags: android, swift, react-native

I recently found out how to change the jsBundle URL in AppDelegate.swift in iOS so i can download my own jsBundle and use this when the app starts:

```
bundleLocation = URL(string: "http://www.example.com/myJsBundle.js")!

let rootView = RCTRootView(bundleURL: bundleLocation, moduleName: "ReactApp", initialProperties: nil, launchOptions:launchOptions)

self.bridge = rootView?.bridge

self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let rootViewController = UIViewController()

rootViewController.view = rootView

self.window!.rootViewController = rootViewController;
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

return true
```

When i now want to do the same in an Android project i open the MainApplication.java file and see this code:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

My question is now, where and how can i define a custom URL for the jsBundle in Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether the intended use is for debugging or to use in production:

**debugging**

See [connecting-to-the-development-server](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#connecting-to-the-development-server) on how to switch `url` and `port` for android.

**production**

As far as I am aware you need to download the bundle first and then use the overridden method `getJSBundleFile` on `ReactNativeHost` instance (created as per the provided code snippet in the question)

```
@Override
protected String getJSBundleFile() {
  return pathToBundleFileDownloaded; // change this
}
```

If the intended use is for production, I suggest looking at some of the libraries out there that offer this kind of functionality. [CodePush](http://microsoft.github.io/code-push/) is a good example and is free.

Comment: My testing bundle is currently in the assets folder. So i tried the URL: file:///android_asset/index.android.bundle. But this produces the error: No such file or directory. Any ideas which will be the correct path?

Comment: if you are adding your bundle to the assets folder with the name `index.android.bundle`, this is the default location. I would then not override `getJSBundleFile` and return false in the method `getUseDeveloperSupport` or build `release`.